# how to change font color of excel cell based on other cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have two worksheet in one workbook. one cell in worksheet "A" has red font color. I want to another cell is worksheet "B" have same font color and content. but the color of cell in "B" should be changed to appropriate color if font color of cell in "A" changed.

for example :cell A1 in sheet "A" is 120 in black color. in sheet "B" cell B1 is B1=A!A1 and it is black. by changing A1 font color to Red(in sheet "A") , B1 cell color in sheet "B" remain black while I want to change its color to Red .

Answer (score 0):

As Per [**Use a formula to apply conditional formatting**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)

> Conditional formatting quickly highlights important information in a
>   spreadsheet. But sometimes the built-in formatting rules don’t go
>   quite far enough. Adding your own formula to a conditional formatting
>   rule gives it a power boost to help you do things the built-in rules
>   can’t do.
>
> **Create conditional formatting rules with formula**
>
> For example, let’s say you track your dental patients’ birthdays to
>   see whose is coming up and then mark them as having received a Happy
>   Birthday greeting from you.
>
> In this worksheet, we see the information we want by using conditional
>   formatting, driven by two rules that each contain a formula. The first
>   rule, in column A, formats future birthdays, and the rule in column C
>   formats cells as soon as “Y” is entered, indicating that the birthday
>   greeting has been sent.
>
> [image]
>
> **To create the first rule:**
>
> 1. Select cells A2 through A7. Do this by dragging from A2 to A7.
> 2. Then, click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule.
> 3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, click Use a formula to
>      determine which cells to format.
> 4. Under Format values where this formula is true, type the formula:
>      =A2>TODAY()
> 5. The formula uses the TODAY function to see if the dates in column A
>      are greater than today (in the future). If so, the cells are
>      formatted.
> 6. Click Format.
> 7. In the Color box, select Red. In the Font Style box, select Bold.
> 8. Click OK until the dialog boxes are closed.
>       The formatting is applied to column A.
>
> **To create the second rule:**
>
> 9. Select cells C2 through C7.
> 10. Repeat steps 2 through 4 above, and enter this formula: =C2="Y"
>
> The formula tests to see if the cells in column C contain “Y” (the
>   quotation marks around the Y tell Excel that this is text). If so, the
>   cells are formatted.
>
> 11. In the Color box, select White. In the Font Style box, select Bold.
> 12. Click the Fill tab and select Green.
>
> The formatting is applied to column C.

As Per [**Create a cell reference to another worksheet**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa)

> You can refer to cells that are on other worksheets in the same
>   workbook by prepending the name of the worksheet followed by an
>   exclamation point (!) to the start of the cell reference. In the
>   following example, the worksheet function named AVERAGE calculates the
>   average value for the range B1:B10 on the worksheet named Marketing in
>   the same workbook.
>
> [image]
>
> Reference to a range of cells on another worksheet in the same
>   workbook
>
> 1. Refers to the worksheet named Marketing
> 2. Refers to the range of cells between B1 and B10, inclusively
> 3. Separates the worksheet reference from the cell range reference
> 4. Click the cell in which you want to enter the formula.
> 5. In the formula bar  Button image , type = (equal sign) and the formula you want to use.
> 6. Click the tab for the worksheet to be referenced.
>
> Select the cell or range of cells to be referenced.

Comment: thank you for detail but please see more explanation added to my question

Comment: @RezaRezai, I updated the answer. Also, Keep habit of Upvoting & accepting answers once your issues are resolved.

Comment: I want to relate color of text in two cell to each other as explained in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using VBA, add this code to your "B" sheet object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Worksheets("B").Range("B1").Font.Color = Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Font.Color

End Sub
```